# how to center a div between another two (left and right) divs?

Tags: html, css

what i want to achieve is something like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/mqndJ/), that is, to have 3 buttons, one to the left, one in the center, and one to the right, and in the same "line", but using css and divs, since I know using tables for laying out pages is just wrong.

I guess i need to use floats, and i already achieved to have the left and right divs correctly, but I can't get the center div to be, well, centered, it just jumps out of the line of the other two.

My attempt:

html:

```
<div class="left" ><input type="button" value="left" /></div>
<!--<div class="center" ><input type="button" value="center" /></div>-->
<div class="right" ><input type="button" value="right" /></div>

<!-- If I uncomment the center div, the right one appears in another block, below the others-->
```

css:

```
.left {
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
.center{
    /*what do i put here??*/
}
```

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UNhSM/) with that, to mess up with.

How can I achieve it, and get the closest to the table layout example?

Note: I've looked in other similar questions, but I couldn't find one with the exact same issue.

Comment: I took a second look at my solution and indeed there was an issue as you pointed out.  I improved the solution and the explanation.  All the best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width: 33.3%
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width: 33.3%;
    text-align: right;
}
.center{
    float: left;
    width: 33.3%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisP/mqKb3/1/)

**Edit in response to comment**

If you want to include borders, you'll need to update the widths accordingly.  CSS uses a [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) in which total width is margin + border + padding + content (controlled by width property).  Here is a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisP/n9X4Z/) that adds 1px borders to each `div` and updates the width accordingly.

Comment: this works fine UNTIL I put borders or margins to the divs (even if just 1px) [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/mqKb3/2/), since the added pixels make them "not fit" in a single line with their 33.3% width. Is it possible to set the width of elements CONSIDERING their margin and border? I mean, to always have 33.3% (a third) but to work despite the margin, border, padding of elements?.

Comment: See my updated answer.  My original answer fixed your problem as originally stated.  This updated answer provides additional information about how CSS controls element widths and shows a version of the demo with borders.  You'll need to think about the widths of your elements (see the link to info about the box model) and adjust the CSS to fit your needs.

Comment: thanks! I was aware of the box model, but I had no idea you could set variable widths (or other dimensions) using that `calc()` function! It would be even better if instead of manually puting that `-2px` (based on the two sides of the 1px border), it could be calculated automatically. But I guess that is matter to another question. Thanks again.

Comment: Great!  If I have answered your question please accept my response.  If you want to have variables like that, you should learn about [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Comment: Although I consider Marc Audet's answer more elegant, simple and straightforward, I accept yours for being more useful, and for considering the 1/3 condition (although not necesary, because i only need the divs to be left, center, right, regardless their width.) =P . I also just learnt that jQuery has the .outerWidth() method which returns the "real" width of elements, considering padding, border and margins. And I'll look into LESS, thanks.

Comment: You can also use outlines instead of borders. They have no affect on the size of the box.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick (2nd revision).

Move the `.center` div after the two floated elements:

```
<div class="left">
    <input type="button" value="left" />
</div>
<div class="right">
    <input type="button" value="right" />
</div>
<div class="center">
    <input type="button" value="center" />
</div>
```

for the CSS, you can simply use `text-align: center` to center the input button since it is an inline element.

```
.left {
    float:left;
}
.right {
    float:right;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
    outline: 1px dotted blue; /* to show content box limits */
    margin: 0 150px;
}
```

**How This Works**

Floated elements are positioned to either the left or right edge of the parent container with the top edge either adjacent to the top of the parent container OR the bottom edge of the closest block element before the floated element.

If you want the left and right floated elements to appear on the same horizontal line, they need to be adjacent to each other, which is why the `.center` element appears after the left and right floats.

The content from the `.center` element (in this case, the input button) wraps around the left and right floated elements, which means that the length of the inline box (an imaginary box that holds the content) is shortened to make room for the floated elements, which means that the content line extends from the right edge of the left element to the left edge of the right element.  When you use `text-align: center`, the input button is centered on this shortened inline box, which is why the element appears off center if the left and right buttons have different lengths.

To work around that, you need to allow some room for the floats.  One simple way of doing this is to set equal left and right margins, for example, `margin: 0 150px`.

If the labels are known ahead of time, the margin value is easy enough to figure out.

However, for this to work, the length of the three labels must be less than the length of the line, otherwise, the centering is impossible.

Please see updated demo.

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/kQstT)

Comment: this works perfectly! but please could you explain why the .center div needs to be AFTER the other two and still works? I am new to css layouts.

Comment: Update, I found out that in order for the middle div de be centered (relative to the page), the other two divs need to be the same width. But if either of them is another size, the center div is no longer centered to the page. It is centered relative to the empty space of the other two divs, but that is not the desired behaviour. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/UNhSM/9/).

Comment: I just took a look at the case of longer test labels, interesting result, not quite sure why, but I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks for the update! good explanation. Another solution is that instead of setting the margin for the center div, I set the SAME width for both the left and right divs, which guarantees that the center div will be centered (as long as the remaining space is enough to hold it, as you mention), [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/kQstT/2/), Interestingly enough, now the outline of the center div spans across the whole page! (gonna look for differences between border and outline) Thank you very much!

Comment: oh wait! now i see that in my updated version (see comment above) now the right div button isn't aligned to the right! but to the left of its corresponding 150px width div. To fix it I added a `text-align:right` to the right div, but its getting more complicated, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/kQstT/4/). I now like the `margin:0 150px` solution best! lol

Comment: For a simple HTML construction, there is quite a bit  going on.  Floats are quite interesting, take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290969/how-does-the-margin-work/16549655#16549655 You are getting the hang of it!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://oocss.org/grids_docs.html

I use this for everything. It's extremely easy and extensible.

Short-term answer:

```
.unit {
    float: left;
}
.last-unit {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
}
.size1of3 {
    width: width:33.33333%;
}
.pull-content-right {
    text-align: right;
}
.pull-content-left {
    text-align: left;
}
.center-content {
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="line">
    <div class="unit size1of3 pull-content-left">
    </div>
    <div class="unit size1of3 center-content">
    </div>
    <div class="unit size1of3 last-unit pull-content-right">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem I see, is that the right div's text is not aligned to the right as I need, in fact it seems to BE aligned to its divs right side, but such div is no longer spaning 33%, but only about 50% of the last third. [see here](http://jsbin.com/ilobig/1/edit), how can i adjust that? Plus, what the .line class css needs to be? thanks

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: i left out some of the hacks included in OOCSS grids, thinking that you were using chrome..

Comment: I am using firefox. However, the answer should be browser indpenedent.

Comment: Seems to work in firefox for me. I left the hacks out for brevity.

Comment: Ultimately, for grid layouts, please take a look at OOCSS grids. They'll save you some time. The code provided is a subset of what it offers.